# JSF 2.2 resources in subdirectories of library

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

With JSF 2.1 the following worked for me fine.

Given the structure:

resources
  \_mytheme
     \_img
         \_logo.png

And to include it, I used:

`<h:graphicImage library="mytheme" name="img/logo.png" />`

Now i swittched to JSF 2.2 on Glassfish 4 to have the complete JEE7 Stack and i dont get the resources in subfolders by using a `/` in name attribute.
I just get `jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library` from glassfish.

Is there anything new on JSF 2.2, that i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. As it turned out, my glassfish had some bad cache. Neither hot redeploying, nor restarting helped.
After clearing the whole ear and all it references in the domain and deploying a fresh copy, everything worked fine as expected.